# how to insert new record in a relational table using prisma

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, prisma

I have issue with creating a record to the module `room`
it works when I tried to insert a new element in the user table but with the room it didn't work
here's an image for more info[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxval.jpg)

````
root@70cfe0072344:/usr/src/api# yarn prisma migrate dev
yarn run v1.22.19
$ /usr/src/api/node_modules/.bin/prisma migrate dev
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "trandandan", schema "public" at "postgres:5432"

Already in sync, no schema change or pending migration was found.

✔ Generated Prisma Client (4.7.1 | library) to ./node_modules/@prisma/client in 99ms


Done in 3.36s.
root@70cfe0072344:/usr/src/api# yarn prisma generate
yarn run v1.22.19
$ /usr/src/api/node_modules/.bin/prisma generate
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma

✔ Generated Prisma Client (4.7.1 | library) to ./node_modules/@prisma/client in 90ms
You can now start using Prisma Client in your code. Reference: https://pris.ly/d/client
```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()
```
Done in 1.64s.
root@70cfe0072344:/usr/src/api#
````

I tried to run the command `yarn prisma migrate dev` and `yarn prisma generate` in both the container and host but it didn't work
Here is my docker-compose file for reference :

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: development
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/src/api
      - /usr/src/api/node_modules
    ports:
      - ${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}
      - 5555:5555 # for prisma studio
      - 9229:9229 # for debugging
    command: yarn start:dev
    networks:
      - webnet
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:14
    networks:
      - webnet
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
networks:
  webnet:
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Comment: For future StackOverflow questions, please paste the relevant code/errors into the question body instead of uploading a picture. See "Help others reproduce the problem" on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What version of Prisma are you using? What was the output of running `yarn prisma migrate dev` and `yarn prisma generate`? Can you add that to the body of your post?

Comment: @SheaHunterBelsky I did add the result of the 2 commands